# Change Running Total to percentage of population instead of a number in DAX Power Bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have this table (running total is a measure, I just use it for visualization)

[image: Table]

When I apply a filter to the date dimension from 2018-01-01 to 2022-01-01, I get this data:

[image: Table]

"Running Total" is produced using this measure:

[image: Code]

**If I want to have "Running Total" displayed as a percentage out of the measure "TotalPopulation" (which is just a whole number that changes dynamically when filters are applied), how do I achieve this?**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried

```
DIVIDE([Running Total],[TotalPopulation])
```